# Javascript function load page delay

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a Javascript, that will delay the loading of an jsp page for 2 minutes. it must not initially load, wait the 2 minutes then load that page.

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout( function(){ window.location = "my.jsp"; }, 120000 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a Javascript function with while loop and tested it, I don't know why the browser keeps warning about killing the process.

```
function delayLoading() {
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   while(true) {
      var end = new Date().getTime();
      var diff = end - start;
      if(diff >= (2 * 60 * 1000)) {
          break;
      }
   }
}();
```

Comment: If memory serves me correctly, conditional loops that last an extended period of time are usually detected by the browser and the user is typically given the option to cancel the script or, in your case, kill the process to stop it.

Comment: I guess it's not possible to hold the paging from loading then. Upto 1 second is okay but 2 minutes is way too much.